# search a multiline string and get some values from string php

Tags: php, string, variables, search

there is a php variable like this `$variable='a b c d 
e f g h 
i j k l'`
 is it possible to get the central line e f g h in the variable and remove the rest. provided that values of all three lines are unknown.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply split the string, using the new line '\n' character

```
$mline = 'a b c d 
e f g h 
i j k l';
$your_array = explode("\n", $mline); 

echo $your_array[1]; //Specific solution
echo $your_array[ceil(count($your_array)/2)]; //General solution
```

Comment: thank u problem is solved. your answer was really helpful